# Find all representatives of $3 \times 3$ matrices satisfying $A^4+2A^3-A^2-2A=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Here is my attempt:

Note that $A$ satisfies the polynomial $p(t)=t^4-2t^3-t^2-2t=t(t-1)(t+2)(t+1)$. Thus the minimal polynomial of $A$ must split. Consequently $A$ is diagonalizable. We can choose a representative diagonal matrix for each of the following cases:

1. The minimal polynomial is of the form $t-a$, where $a\in
       \{0,1,-2,-1\}$. In this case the characteristic polynomial is
   $(t-a)^3$. This case yields four representatives, each a diagonal
   matrix with all diagonal entries $a$.
2. The minimal polynomial is of the form $(t-a)(t-b)$, $a$ and $b$ are
   distinct and one of $\{0,1,-2,-1\}$. In this case, the
   characteristic polynomial is $(t-a)^2(t-b)$ or $(t-a)(t-b)^2$. This
   case yields twelve representatives, with two consecutive diagonal
   entries the same value and the other one a different distinct value
   (from the set $\{0,1,-2,-1\}$).
3. The minimal polynomial is of the form $(t-a)(t-b)(t-c)$ so the
   characteristic polynomial is equal to the minimal polynomial.
   Consequently, there are $4$ representatives consisting of matrices
   with distinct diagonal entries from the set $\{0,1,-2,-1\}$.

Are these all the possible representatives? Have I over counted? Is this the right way to approach such problems?

Comment: You have covered this perfectly.

Comment: The answer looks good! Just consider though that if the field is for example the finite field $GF(3)$ the situation is different, so is always good to fix the context...